# Icons disappearing from notification area (systray) under WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, icons, notification-area

Quite often when I start up my WinXP SP3 (updated to the max), some icons in systray are missing. Task manager shows that the software to whom these icons belong is running. Restarting explorer (killing via Task Manager and then running again) brings all the icons back. The icons disappearing are pretty much on random. Sometimes even the Volume icon disappears.

Has anyone had anything like that and is there any fix to this?

(Preemptive reply - no, I've disabled inactive icon hiding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180409043404/http://winhlp.com/node/16) has a fantastic list of explanations and solutions. I won't even try to summarize it here.