# Apps sometimes don't show on system tray

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, notification-area

I have a problem that sometimes some apps don't show on system tray but sometimes they do show. They don't appear on system tray but they are running if seen from task bar.

What is wrong?

Looking for your helpful answers.

OS: Windows XP

**Edit:** Some apps include nimbuzz, download accelerator plus, etc. The Windows is working perfectly well, i have also up-to-date anti-virus installed so nothing wrong with Windows.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding which applications?  Most applications don't have system tray icons.

Comment: You're sure your apps aren't designed to hide the system tray icons when they aren't minimized? Doesn't quite sound like that's what happening but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: yes i am sure they go to system tray and sometimes they work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Icons disappearing from notification area (systray) under WinXP](http://superuser.com/questions/32140/icons-disappearing-from-notification-area-systray-under-winxp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you don't see your tray icons (but the application is running in the background), has Windows Explorer crashed?

If yes that why the icons disappear. Windows Explorer will (in most cases) restart. But some of the tray icons will disappear.

The only way I have seen around it is:

1. Either close that application & restart it. (Tedious)
2. Log off & login again.