# System tray icons no longer display at Windows start up

Tags: windows-xp, boot, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Icons disappearing from notification area (systray) under WinXP](https://superuser.com/questions/32140/icons-disappearing-from-notification-area-systray-under-winxp)

Recently Windows XP has begun not showing any system tray icons at start up. I used to have about 6 applications that would load to the system tray at Windows start up but now only the antivirus app shows there. All the relevant processes are loaded into memory (confirmed using Task Manager).

If I log out and then log back into Windows all the system tray icons appear.

1. What could be causing this?
2. How can I prevent this and get all system tray icons again at start up?

I don't recall doing anything specifically that could have caused this.

I have tried changing notification settings in the task bar. I have tried using CCleaner to clear the notification cache.

It's an irritating problem because some of these apps can only be accessed via the system tray.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: right click start then properties then taskbar then customize.. you can get a list of what is in the system tray and choose always hide or always show. the answer may be there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Icons disappearing from notification area (systray) under WinXP](http://superuser.com/questions/32140/icons-disappearing-from-notification-area-systray-under-winxp) also see [Apps sometimes don't show on system tray](http://superuser.com/questions/99690/apps-sometimes-dont-show-on-system-tray)

Comment: @barlop I've already tried that (as stated in the question).

Comment: @techie007 My question is indeed a duplicate of that question and the answer given (the article linked) provided a solution to my question. I had recently set icons to show for networked uPnP devices and this corresponds with the time this problem started happening. Disabling uPnP icons caused the system tray icons to show again at Windows startup. Thanks.